# HashSet output of Map

Tags: java

I have the `Map`, with a `String` keys and `HashSet` values:

```
Set<String> values = new HashSet<String>();
values.add("values1");
values.add("values2");
Map<String, Set> maps = new HashMap<String, Set>();
maps.put("TestKey", values);
```

I try to bring all the data in the format of the

```
key values ​​values ​​//in one line
```

But I'm getting:

```
key [values, ​​values]
```

Deduce elements I here so:

```
for(Entry<String, Set> e : maps.entrySet()) {
   System.out.println(e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue());
}
```

Please help me to fix output.

**UPD**

and if I want to write it all down in the file, what do I do? in the same format in one line..

this option does not work:

```
FileWriter wr = null;
        PrintWriter pw;
        try {
            wr = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
            pw = new PrintWriter(wr);

        for(Entry<String, Set<String>> e : my.entrySet()) {
               pw.print(e.getKey());
               for(String s: e.getValue()) pw.print(" " + s);
               pw.println();
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Why not iterate over `e.getValue()` and print each entry as you'd prefer?

Comment: What you are getting in the normal output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I try to bring all the data in the format of the
>
> key values ​​values ​​(in one line)

This means you have to use this format.

```
Map<String, Set<String>> maps = ...

for(Entry<String, Set<String>> e : maps.entrySet()) {
   System.out.print(e.getKey());
   for(String s: e.getValue()) System.out.print(" " + s);
   System.out.println();
}
```